# Qual a diferença entre a exceção MySQL Trigger e MySQL Event?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, trigger, agendamento

Gostaria de criar um **agendador de disparo de e-mail**, se possível, sem uso do `cron`, e gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isso através do **MySQL**.

Pesquisando pela Internet eu vi alguns exemplos de criação de evento **sem uso de cron**:

```
CREATE EVENT PurgeLogTable
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK
DO
BEGIN
DELETE FROM `logs` WHERE `LogTime` <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
INSERT INTO `audit` (`AuditDate`, `Message`) VALUES(NOW(), "Log table purged succesfully!");
END
```

E um exemplo de disparo de e-mail usando *trigger*, só não sei se funciona, pois não testei:

```
CREATE TRIGGER send_emailverifier AFTER INSERT, UPDATE ON tbl_users 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM email_bodies WHERE EmailID = 1; 
SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE ClientID = @ClientID 
INSERT INTO tbl_emailverify VALUES (UUID, tbl_users.ClientID, OLD.CltEmail, NEW.CltEmail) 
SELECT concat("To: ",NEW.CltEmail & "," & OLD.CltEmail), 
"From: triggers@yourmysqlserver.whatever", 
concat("Subject: ",NEW.subject), 
"", 
email_bodies.EmailContent 
INTO OUTFILE "/inetpub/mailroot/pickup/mail.eml" 
FIELDS TERMINATED by '\r\n'; 
END
```

Mas minha dúvida é pertinente quanto à maneira de como poderia avisar um disparador de e-mail, para que acione o URL de envio, exemplo:

```
/enviar-emails/go
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eles têm propósitos bem diferentes, como a sintaxe apresentada na pergunta já dá uma dica.

O [`TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) é um recurso antigo dos bancos de dados em geral para disparar - como o próprio nome diz - uma execução de algo quando algo ocorre em uma tabela. Uma mudança nos dados (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) provoca a ação secundária.

O [`EVENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-syntax.html) é um recurso relativamente novo que é determinado pelo tempo, é um agendador. É uma forma de garantir que uma ação seja executada de tempos em tempos, independente do que ocorre no banco de dados. Ele é uma espécie de `cron` do banco de dados.

Então depende do objetivo para disparar o e-mail. Toda vez que um e-mail é inserido ou atualizado na tabela, precisa dispará-lo? Use o `TRIGGER`, como mostra o código acima. Se o envio - mesmo que seletivamente - deve ser feito de tempos em tempos, independente do que ocorre no banco de dados, use o `EVENT`.

A ação que ambos executam podem ser basicamente a mesma. Claro que há algumas limitações no `EVENT` porque ele não está manipulando dados. Por exemplo, ele não tem uma versão velha ou nova do dado que pode ser usado no `TRIGGER`, mas é uma limitação que não atrapalha porque nem faria sentido ter isto em algo que não está atualizando os dados.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.