# Como implementar o padrão Observer na prática, com banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, observer-pattern

Estou estudando alguns padrões de projetos, e no momento estou aprendendo sobre o padrão *observer*. Já li em livros, vi algumas aulas no Youtube, fiz os exemplos e tudo mais.

Mas agora gostaria de implementar na prática inserindo dados no banco de dados, para usar em um projeto que estou trabalhando atualmente.

Minha situação: Tenho uma base com 3 tabelas(`Setor`, `Pessoa`, `PessoaSetor`). É um relacionamento "muitos para muitos". Todo setor pode ter mais de um responsável, essa informação está na tabela PessoaSetor.

O que eu preciso: toda vez que um pessoa for cadastrada em um setor, manda uma notificação para os responsáveis pelo setor. No caso, a notificação pode ser uma tabela a parte.

Comment: O melhor seria você dar uma situação, um problema que quer resolver usando o padrão. É possível implementar um observer em bancos de inúmeras formas, usando stored procedures/funções ou triggers, vai depender do caso.

Comment: [Update] coloquei meu problema que quero resolver

Comment: Essa é a situação perfeita para usar [triggers](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatilho_(banco_de_dados)) (que são essencialmente observers "padrão" de rdbms's), se você especificar qual banco de dados está usando vai facilitar porque o uso varia conforme o tipo.

Comment: @FábioLima A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e ajudar a todos entdner isso. Também pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

A pergunta não dá muitos detalhes, é genérica demais, então não posso dar uma resposta tão precisa, mas basicamente o padrão *observer* é aplicado em banco de dados usando o recurso de gatilhos.

Todo banco de dados relacional de grande utilização possui o comando [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) onde se define uma ação a ser executada quando alguma alteração no banco de dados ocorre, exatamente o que determina este padrão. Uma destas ações é chamar alguma rotina, um executável e em alguns banco de dados é possível só enviar uma notificação para o(s) cliente(s) conectado. Aí depende do banco para saber se será mais simples e bem adequado fazer algo assim. [Consulte a documentação específica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) do seu banco de dados.

Pode parecer ser uma solução simples e óbvia para usar, mas usar gatilhos é cheio de truques e mesmo desenvolvedores experientes podem cair em armadilhas. Estou passando a técnica, mas não dizendo que é a melhor maneira de lidar com isto. Como sempre, tudo depende do caso. Como qualquer padrão de projeto ele pode ser abusado.

Alguns DBs podem ter outros mecanismos que fazem algo parecido, exemplo: [evento do MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103700/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).