# Diferença entre Triggers e Stored Procedures

Tags: banco-de-dados, trigger, stored-procedures

Quais são as diferenças entre Triggers e Stored Procedures?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## *Stored Procedures*

São como funções para serem chamadas por diversas circunstâncias. Em tese podem fazer qualquer coisa, até mesmo não relacionadas tão diretamente com as tabelas, ainda que raro.

Não pense que há algo muito mais complexo que isso.

Claro que elas ficam armazenadas dentro do banco de dados, não ficam na sua aplicação. Você até pode usar o SQL para invocá-las, mas é algo indireto, o banco de dados é que cuida dela.

Quando se programa criamos basicamente duas coisas: estrutura de dados e algoritmos. Em códigos considerados modernos (ainda que seja questionável dizer isso) é normal fazer isso em classes que tem tanto a estrutura (os membros com estado) e os algoritmos relacionados (os métodos). Em código mais procedural isso é isolado. É uma pena que muitos programadores hoje nem tem ideia de que isso é possível e as vantagens de fazer desta forma.

No banco de dados a estrutura é a tabela. As *stored procedures* são os métodos. Note que não há vinculação direta entre elas e as tabelas.

[Definição da Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedimento_armazenado):

> Procedimento armazenado ou Stored Procedure é uma coleção de comandos em SQL para "dispensamento" de banco de dados. Encapsula tarefas repetitivas, aceita parâmetros de entrada e retorna um valor de status (para indicar aceitação ou falha na execução). O procedimento armazenado pode reduzir o tráfego na rede, visto que os comandos são executados diretamente no servidor. Além de melhorar a performance, criar mecanismos de segurança entre a manipulação dos dados do Banco de Dados.

Então, a grosso modo, é como se tivesse um executável ou *scripts* dentro do banco de dados. Sempre que precisar que aquilo seja executado ele pode ser chamado.

#### Como usar

Para chamar uma *stored procedure* normalmente tem um comando `EXECUTE` ou `CALL`, ou `DO` ou `RUN`, dependendo do banco de dados. É um comando SQL como outro qualquer. Chamou, executa o que precisa.

Assim como pode criar, modificar, e apagar tabelas, pode fazer o mesmo com *sprocs*, elas são objetos do banco de dados. Tem comando SQL para isso. [Exemplo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE HumanResources.uspGetEmployeesTest2   
    @LastName nvarchar(50),   
    @FirstName nvarchar(50)   
AS   

    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, Department  
    FROM HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartmentHistory  
    WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName  
    AND EndDate IS NULL;  
GO
```

Note que o que tem `@` são os parâmetros que podem ser passados para ela. O resto são comando da linguagem, que obviamente pode executar qualquer comando SQL, mas não só. [É uma linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101) como outra qualquer (ao contrário do SQL que não é uma linguagem de programação).

A linguagem tem variáveis, desvios condicionais ou incondicionais, faz cálculos de todo tipo, enfim, é completa. [Exemplo com `IF` e variáveis](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15):

```
DECLARE @maxWeight float, @productKey integer  
SET @maxWeight = 100.00  
SET @productKey = 424  
IF @maxWeight <= (SELECT Weight from DimProduct 
                  WHERE ProductKey = @productKey)   
    (SELECT @productKey AS ProductKey, EnglishDescription, Weight, 
    'This product is too heavy to ship and is only available for pickup.' 
        AS ShippingStatus
    FROM DimProduct WHERE ProductKey = @productKey);  
ELSE  
    (SELECT @productKey AS ProductKey, EnglishDescription, Weight, 
    'This product is available for shipping or pickup.' 
        AS ShippingStatus
    FROM DimProduct WHERE ProductKey = @productKey);
```

[Referência do T-SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15) (a linguagem do SQL Server). Cada banco de dados tem sua própria linguagem, outro exemplo é a [PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/toc.htm).

#### Onde é usada

Sempre que precisar criar uma validação, uma operação que deva ser executada em determinadas circunstâncias para manutenção ou adaptação de dados ela pode ser útil.

Ela tem uma vantagem que é toda executada no banco de dados sem precisar sair dele. Mas há técnicas para evitar isso sem o uso das *sprocs*. Normalmente é útil para ter uma forma canônica de fazer algo no banco de dados. É como fazer um [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). Mas dá para fazer o mesmo na aplicação, se souber o que está fazendo.

Eu vivo sem elas há bastante tempo. Há quem goste muito, mas elas são menos úteis do que parece na maioria dos casos onde o banco de dados é usado com aplicações.

[Leitura útil para entender o que foi perguntado na duplicata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15739/101).

## *Trigger*

Como o nome (gatilho) diz, é um mecanismo de notificação de que algo aconteceu (uma inserção, atualização ou remoção) e portanto alguma ação deve ser executada.

O gatilho em si é só esse mecanismo. Claro que ele tem que executar uma ação, e ela pode ser até mesmo chamar uma *stored procedure*. Se for muito simples a ação pode ser declarada ali mesmo junto da declaração do gatilho, como uma *sproc*.

A grosso modo é a [implementação do padrão Observer no banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117545/101).

Ele também é um objeto do banco de dados e pode ser criado, alterado ou removido. [Exemplo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15):

```
CREATE TRIGGER reminder2  
ON Sales.Customer  
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE   
AS  
   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
        @profile_name = 'AdventureWorks2012 Administrator',  
        @recipients = 'danw@Adventure-Works.com',  
        @body = 'Don''t forget to print a report for the sales force.',  
        @subject = 'Reminder';  
GO
```

Nesse caso ele será usado na tabela `Sales.Customer` , sempre que ocorrer um `INSERT`, `UPDATE` ou `DELETE` ele vai executar o procedimento seguinte, logo após o comando SQL de manipulação da tabela ser executada (há casos que se prefere executar antes). No caso está chamando uma *sproc* armazenada no DB.

Outro exemplo onde o procedimento já está junto do gatilho:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Purchasing.LowCredit ON Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader  
AFTER INSERT  
AS  
IF EXISTS (SELECT *  
           FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader AS p   
           JOIN inserted AS i   
           ON p.PurchaseOrderID = i.PurchaseOrderID   
           JOIN Purchasing.Vendor AS v   
           ON v.BusinessEntityID = p.VendorID  
           WHERE v.CreditRating = 5  
          )  
BEGIN  
RAISERROR ('A vendor''s credit rating is too low to accept new  
purchase orders.', 16, 1);  
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
RETURN   
END;  
GO
```

Essa executa um código descrito logo após uma interação ocorrida na tabela `Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader`.

Os eventos que ele trata não se limitam aos comandos usando em tabelas:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ddl_trig_database   
ON ALL SERVER   
FOR CREATE_DATABASE   
AS   
    PRINT 'Database Created.'  
    SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)')  
GO
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/ProcedureTrigger.sql).

#### Utilidade

Pense em um cliente que é apagado. O que ocorre quando toda informação gerada para ele? Fica tudo órfão. Então o correto é que se fizer o `DELETE` no cliente, apague tudo o que se refere a ele. Normalmente esse apagar na verdade é transportar para um arquivo morto.

Esse nem é o melhor exemplo porque tem razões para não fazer isso, mas é simples de entender. Como transporta para o arquivo morto garantidamente se o cliente for removido? Através de um gatilho.

Outro exemplo: aqui no site você recebe um voto, isso atualiza a tabela de do *post* que recebeu o voto. Sua reputação deve subir ou cair. Como garantir que uma operação que grava um voto em uma postagem atualize a reputação do usuário? Cria um gatilho que dispara essa atualização para você.

Também pode ser usado em validação no entrada de dados na tabela. Pode pensar que isso já pode ser feito com outros mecanismos no banco de dados. Sim, mas de forma padronizada e simples. Quando precisa de algo mais complexo é necessário criar um algoritmo na linguagem de programação do banco de dados, e o mais importante, é preciso garantir que isso seja executado toda vez que o dado é inserido ou alterado para garantir que ele está de acordo com o pretendido.

Um exemplo clássico é criar uma tabela de auditoria sempre que um dado será inserido, modificado ou apagado da tabela. Lá pode colocar os que foi modificado, quem fez, quando, e outras informações úteis.

Ele é útil para garantir a integridade referencial do modelo, não importa o que aconteça no banco de dados, é garantido que todas as consequências disso sejam refletidas de maneira correta no banco de dados todo no mesmo momento.

Tem bem mais utilidade que uma simples *sproc*. Mas é preciso tomar cuidado para não abusar (vejo muito abuso). Se ficar disparando gatilho sem um ótimo motivo para fazê-lo pode comprometer a performance e começar fazer lambança.