# Excluir e realocar índice

Tags: sql, sql-server, estrutura-de-dados, índices

Como devo associar dados para ter um db *SQL Server 2017* com um bom desempenho. Estou fazendo uma associação de dados e por ser novo nesta área me sinto um pouco perdido.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura como exemplo:

[image: imagem 1.1]

Digamos que as estruturas acima têm os seguintes dados:

[image: imagem 1.2]
[image: imagem 1.3]

#### Excluir e realocar

Usando o exemplo acima procuro uma solução para por exemplo, se o "*u2*" na tabela `Account` for excluído, o `u3` ser realocado para o índice 2 e a mesma mudança acontecer na tabela `Account_Data`.

#### Dúvidas

Este tipo de ação é possível com SQL puro?

Devo usar outra linguagem para gerenciar estes eventos?

Comment: simplesmente, não faça isso. Id é a chave daquele registro e não deve ser alterada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estou achando estranho ter essas duas tabelas separadas, mas como não há descrição do caso pode ser que precise mesmo. Pelo nome e estrutura das tabelas algo me diz que não precisa.

Se quer que uma ação em uma tabela dispare ação em outra tabela precisa usar [gatilhos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164400/101). Mas se só existir uma tabela nem precisa disto :)

A chave primária nunca deve ser mudada no banco de dados. Não importa que ficará buracos. A única exceção é se você criar uma rotina que modifique todas as referências para ela em todo o banco de dados e possa garantir que estas chaves não foram usadas em qualquer lugar fora do DB. Mas eu não faria isto. praticamente zero vantagens e há riscos.

O que você chama de índice é essa chave, índice é um conjunto de chaves.

Tentar fazer o que está pretendendo não fará o banco de dados ser mais rápido, isto é micro otimização e daquelas que não trazem ganhos. Tem chance até de piorar.

Pra falar a verdade na maioria dos cenários que eu conheço nada deveria ser apagado efetivamente a não ser que a pessoa tenha uma estratégia de como fazer isto corretamente.

Mesmo que queria fazer, não estou vendo a ligação entre uma tabela e outra. Se for o `id` então realmente não precisa de duas tabelas e aí a descrição da pergunta está errada.

Modelar certo, criar os índices certos, fazer as consultas certas, configurar o servidor corretamente, fazer a aplicação do jeito certo e toda arquitetura da solução ser adequada, fazer testes, analisar o uso, ver os gargalos, tudo isto é que fará ter desempenho.

Comment: a resposta me atende bem, se possível me fala se em caso do ID não ser um índice primário, como fazer a realocação, vlw!

Comment: `id` sempre é primário, ou pelo menos deveria. Mesmo que ele não seja, ele servirá para alguma chave estrangeira, então também não pode mexer.

Comment: obrigado, ajudou demais, junto com o código do Rovann Linhalis que posso usar em casos de necessidade, vou levar as dicas de não alterar id e pk.

Answer (score 2):

Respondendo ao seu comentário na resposta do Maniero:

Suponha que você tenha vários registros:

```
n
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Você irá apagar o n 3. Após a exclusão, bastaria efetuar um comando:

```
update tabela set n = n-1 where n > 3;
```

Mas, também como maniero disse, não vejo nada que isso solucione, e algo totalmente desnecessário.

Se quiser que em um select, venha o número da linha de forma sequencial sem saltos, há funções que fazem isso.

Comment: você preencheu as lacunas, kkkk vlw mano, não sendo em índices primários, sua resposta me ajuda bastante.