# Salvar ou não os comandos usados no MySQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysql

Quando você cria um código MySQL e executa, esse código depois de executado, você precisa salvar ele ou não? Ou depois de executado pode esquecer ele? Falo dos comandos que cria tabela, atualizar, inserir, etc.

Comment: Você pode ou não salvar. Depende muito do contexto, se salvar pode usar como base para criar outros scripts ou se não escrever de novo.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

Não precisa, mas você pode gravar em algum arquivo para usar de novo se quiser. Uma coisa não está relacionada com outra.

Eu nem chamaria exatamente de código o que você faz diretamente no MySQL, não deixa de ser, mas em geral são comando soltos. E por isso o que está fazendo provavelmente não será usado igual de novo.

No te que você está usando um processados de comandos, seja o fornecido pelo próprio MySQL em linha de comando ou um outro como o Workbench que parece estar usando.

Se criar um comando que acha que é complexo suficiente e vale a pena usar de novo pode salvar em um arquivo com extensão `.sql` e depois chamá-lo para executar igual.

É possível gravar todos os comandos, inclusive muitas vezes é gravado para funcionar como um *script* para reproduzir os mesmo comandos em outro local, outra instância do banco de dados. Mas é mais comum que esses *scripts* sejam preparados depois e não logo que usa um comando para testar se é o que deseja.

Em geral esse tipo de coisa é mais comum quando está programando em outra linguagem para criar um código que manipule o banco de dados, aí o comando SQL vai dentro do código.

Também é possível usar esses comandos em [*stored procedure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164400/101), mas isso já é bem mais avançado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Ao executar comando em um banco de dados, seja ela qualquer um (SQL server, MySQL e etc) maioria das mudanças realizada ficam gravadas no DB. Exceto quando certos processos são realmente temporários(assunto um pouco mais avançado), quando você executa, insert, update, delete, entre outros. Essas informações ficam gravadas de forma fixa no banco de dados, o que será perdido se não salvar, será a query que são os códigos que você escreve, exemplo:

Select * from tabela X

update tabela X set campo Y = 10

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

O MySQL a grosso modo é um gerenciador de dados, ele sozinho eu diria que não serviria para algo prático, você deve associa-lo a uma linguagem de programação para exibir os resultados obtidos através dos comandos MySQL, desta forma nessa linguagem você "grava" os comandos e executa sempre que precisar modificando somente os valores dos parâmetros.

Exemplo:

> `SELECT * FROM TABELA_A WHERE (CODKEY = :CODIGO)`

Neste caso você mudaria somente o valor de ":CODIGO" e teria dados de registros específicos.

Comandos como CREATE DATABASE, CREATE TABLE, CREATE INDEX e outros são executados somente para criar tabelas e índices e afins, não sendo necessário grava-los, já comandos como INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE e SELECT são muito usados no cotidiano de uma aplicação então como dito acima vale apena grava-los e modificar somente os parametros.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Nesse exato momento eu estou fazendo um projeto simples de CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete) que usa o Python e SQL. Eu salvei o script feito para a criação do Banco de Dados e ainda comentei cada linha.

Os comando e/ou alterações que vão ocorrer, vão ser feitas pela linguagem de programação, no meu caso o Python. Caso você precise fazer uma consulta ou uma alteração que faria direto por uma query, sem a linguagem, acho que seria válido vc salvar (até mesmo no script original)

Acho relevante vc salvar essas coisas pois lá na frente pode te ajudar ou ajudar outra pessoa, dando uma base de como funciona. Além também de ser uma documentação do projeto em si e também pode ajudar a explicar ou entender quando e o porque houve a alteração (caso outra pessoa entre no projeto ou aplicação).

Mas salvando ou não, não vai fazer nenhuma diferença no seu programa. E vc ainda consegue esse código novamente fazendo um `dump` (backup), tendo junto os valores que foram adicionados ao longo do tempo.

Repositório do meu projeto (comecei essa semana):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembre que, todos os projetos que vc for participar/fazer, sempre tem, ou futuramente vai ter, mais pessoas envolvidas. Quanto mais organizado a sua aplicação for, melhor a manutenção e entendimento dela.

Answer (score -1):

Quando você cria um código mysql e executa, esse código depois de executado, você precisa salvar ele ou não ?

**Não. Não precisa. Entretanto, vc poderá até salvar o arquivo e depois usa-lo em outra atividade. Comandos trazem mudanças em seu banco de dados. Preste atenção e tenha cuidado com o que está fazendo, principalmente com o comando *Drop Table*.**