# Qual é a melhor maneira de se monitorar um valor em um banco de dados?

Tags: trigger, cron

Estou trabalhando em um sistema de gerenciamento de itens, no qual preciso monitorar constantemente a quantidade de itens disponíveis. Ao atingir um patamar mínimo pré-definido, o sistema deverá emitir inserir o item em uma lista de alerta para que o mesmo seja reposto.

Qual seria a melhor maneira de realizar esse monitoramento? Uma tarefa cron rodando a cada n segundos ou um trigger que será disparado cada vez que a quantidade seja alterada?

Comment: O único adendo que faço é o "tempo" uma coisa seria <luvas descartáveis em uma unidade de saúde> a reposição tem de ser imediata, outra seria comprar <nacarrão miojo> (fazer pedido etc) para repor o estoque, a "trigger" permite um alerta mais rápido , um "schedulle" poderia resolver o problema se o "tempo" não for fator crítico.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Um [*trigger* é a única opção válida se quiser notificação precisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117545/101). Algo que fique executando de tempos em tempos pode funcionar em alguns cenários bem específicos, mas "sempre" terá uma performance menor. A não ser que o que deseja não é bem verificar de tempos em tempos e o ciclo de atualizações é muito alto, o que não parece ser o caso.

O gatilho garante que toda mudança no banco faça a notificação. Pode ser que deseje isso. Pode ser que deseje de tempos em tempos tenha notificações de tudo. São semânticas diferentes.

O gatilho tem um custo em cada operação, se não precisa dessas notificações na hora, pode ser um custo à toa.

Fazer lotes verificando tem um custo único extra e que fará operações desnecessárias, mas alivia cada atualização e pode optar por fazer isso em horário não crítico. Não vai mudar muito, mas em grandes volumes pode fazer diferença. Você pode deixar a notificação para depois sem problemas? Vai fazer isso frequentemente? Aí eu duvido que seja uma boa opção.

Faça um teste para ver qual funciona melhor para você. Não é fácil escolher, depende da necessidade e a forma de implementar. O perigo está no detalhe.

Este site aqui opta por atualizar certas coisas em lote, mas algumas são feitas na hora. Depende do desejado e de quanto afeta a métrica de performance estabelecida.

Em alguns bancos de dados existem [opções melhores que usar `cron`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103700/101).

Claro que depende da arquitetura de sua solução. Estou considerando que quer fazer no banco de dados. Em geral eu prefiro fazer em outra camada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

### Durante a Transação

Se você tem um sistema, é provável que esse sistema tenha uma camada de serviços ou uma camada de acesso a dados ou de regras de negócio que tratam as transações que o sistema está executando que impedem o acesso direto ao banco de dados.

Se for esse o seu caso, então o melhor seria a sua transação de itens verificar esse *threshold* quando estiver atualizando a quantidade e disparar uma mensagem usando o mecanismo de mensagens do sistema para que fosse gerado esse alerta.

Se o sistema não tem camadas e permite o acesso direto ao banco por qualquer aplicação então a opção de *trigger* vai te garantir de forma mais rápida o reconhecimento dessa condição limite, porém *triggers* podem afetar o desempenho do banco de dados.

A opção do "cron" que você está avaliando é a forma passiva em que você executa uma consulta a cada "X" tempo. Ela tem a desvantagem de você ter que checar todos os itens e isso vai gerar uma consulta mais abrangente no banco. Se o intervalo de busca for pequeno também pode trazer problemas de desempenho. Essa opção seria interessante se você tivesse uma tabela separada do sistema para fazer essas consultas recorrentes.

Eu prefiro a opção de fazer na transação do próprio item porque assim você teria algumas vantagens do *trigger*, que é atuar quando ocorre a alteração em cada item, e poder usar o mecanismo de mensagens da aplicação para atuar de forma assíncrona com essa regra e dessa forma não afetar o desempenho das transações. Você também ficaria com a função independente do banco de dados.

A desvantagem de escolher a transação é se você tem as regras espalhadas pelo sistema. Nesse caso a melhor opção vai ser a *trigger* mesmo.

[Nessa resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16292677/1700943) (em inglês) tem algumas alternativas para uso de *triggers* em banco de dados quando você quer implementar algo como um [*Observer*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36671/43).