# Apagar registro quando a data de uma coluna for atingida

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, trigger

Tenho as tabelas:

[image: modelo]

Em `anuncios` tenho a coluna `expiracao` que recebe a quantidade de dias que aquele anuncio é válido, quero que a cada dia que se passe o banco de dados automaticamente diminua `1` nessa coluna, numa contagem regressiva para desativar o anuncio. E quando chegar em 0, que ele crie um registro na tabela `expiracao` com `expiracao.supermercado` valendo `anuncios.supermecado`. É possível fazer isso com rotinas? Nunca mexi com rotinas, tentei pesquisar mas não entendi, espero que não fechem a pergunta.

Com a resposta do @Maniero eu pesquisei e entendi um pouco, bolei um banco de dados de teste assim:

// Tabela Notificações, substitui tabela expiracao
    --
    -- Estrutura da tabela `notificacao`
    --

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notificacao` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idteste` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mensagem` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

// Tabela Teste, substitui tabela anuncios

```
--
-- Estrutura da tabela `teste`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teste` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `expiracao` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `teste`
--

INSERT INTO `teste` (`id`, `expiracao`, `nome`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Teste01'),
(2, 99, 'Teste02'),
(3, 149, 'Teste03'),
(4, 199, 'Teste04');
```

// Trigger da tabela teste, quando um dado é atualizado olha se a coluna expiracao equivale a 0, se sim, apaga o registro e insere um dado na outra tabela

```
--
-- Acionadores `teste` (TRIGGER)
--
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `geraNotificacao`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `geraNotificacao` BEFORE UPDATE ON `teste`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF teste.expiracao = 0 THEN
INSERT INTO notificacao (`idteste`, `mensagem`) VALUES (teste.id, "Teste apagado!");
DELETE FROM teste WHERE teste.id = OLD.id;
END IF;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

// Evento que a cada 10 segundos decrementa 1 de expiracao

```
DELIMITER $$
--
-- Eventos
--
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `decrementaDia` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND 
STARTS '2016-05-12 15:11:10' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO UPDATE teste SET teste.expiracao = (teste.expiracao - 1) WHERE 1$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Quando executo o *script* nada acontece, na tabela teste não é decrementado o valor de expiração, e também se torna impossível editar manualmente o valor do mesmo.

Comment: Nossa aqui tem um tutorial bom em Sql-Server, porém de mysql não conheço muito. http://imasters.com.br/artigo/257/sql-server/criando-e-executando-jobs-no-sql-server?trace=1519021197&source=single

Comment: Normalmente não muda muito, obrigado. Já procurei bastante sobre isso e não estou conseguindo encontrar.

Comment: no caso do `MSSQL`, você pode criar uma `Job` a ser execuatada diariamente. fazendo uma breve pesqusia, vi que o MySQL tem algo semelhante [`Event Scheduler`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html), então você pode criar um evento que irá decrementar o valor e apagar o registro caso o valor fique abaixo de 0.

Comment: Se preferir, pode dividir as responsabilidades, o `Event Scheduler`apenas decrementar o valor e uma `trigger` no `update` do registro ficará responsavel pela exclusão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obter o que deseja deve criar um agendador. Isso é feito com [`EVENT` que é parecido com `TRIGGERS`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103700/101), mas ocorre de tempo de tempo.

[Documentação do agendador](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html).

Com isso, executa um `UPDATE` de acordo com o que mexer todos os dias (no horário que quiser).

Já a mudança na tabela `expiracao` pode ser feita com um [`TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) na tabela `anuncios` onde cada alteração decidirá se precisa disparar um `INSERT` na outa tabela.

Em linhas gerais é isto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Elaborei um exemplo de acordo com a sua resposta mas não rodou, a tabela fica intacta.. Acrescentei o código do teste na pergunta.

Comment: Atualizando.. O erro está no `trigger`, mas não consigo identificar qual é o erro.

Comment: Eu acho que a edição coloca um novo problema e portanto é uma nova pergunta. Quando a fizer, coloque detalhes do problema e se possível faça um [mcve].

Comment: Consegui fazer criando dois eventos separados, um pra decrementar o dia e outro pra verificar e apagar o registro expirado. Como trigger fiz um para quando um anunio for apagado pelo evento, dando insert na outra tabela. Assim funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado pela ajuda, melhor que um código pronto, fez eu entender e aprender :D