# TRIGGER e ASSERTION sql server

Tags: sql-server

Gostaria de saber como funcionam as TRIGGERS e os ASSERTIONS sou iniciante e não tenho ideia por onde começar?

Comment: Tem algo específico que queira saber? Veja se te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164400/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103700/101. O SQL Server não tem `ASSERTATION`.

Comment: Se é possivel fazer para cada um dos eventos de uma tabela INSERT, SELECT,UPDATE, DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

A sintaxe de criação de gatilhos permite criar procedimentos independentes para as instruções INSERT, UPDATE e DELETE. Também é possível em único procedimento tratar os três tipos de evento. Detalhes na documentação para criação de gatilhos: [CREATE TRIGGER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/ms189799.aspx).

A instrução SELECT não efetua nenhuma alteração no banco de dados, não existindo, assim, gatilho associado a esta instrução.

Em T-SQL ainda não há CREATE ASSERTION. Dependendo do que necessitar, pode ser simulado com o uso de restrição de tabela (*table constraint*) associada a função de usuário.

Na web há vários artigos disponíveis sobre a utilização de gatilhos em T-SQL. Você pode garimpar os resultados da pesquisa por "[sql server trigger](https://www.google.com.br/search?client=ubuntu&q=%22sql%20server%22%20trigger%20-msdn)". Por exemplo:
[Triggers no SQL Server: teoria e prática aplicada em uma situação real](http://www.devmedia.com.br/triggers-no-sql-server-teoria-e-pratica-aplicada-em-uma-situacao-real/28194).

No livro "[Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008: T-SQL Programming](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/inside-t-sql-2008-programming/)", de Itzik Ben-Gan, o capítulo 4 é dedicado aos gatilhos.